# Creating a background website in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know what's the best way to create a background-based website.
I'm using Bootstrap and the thing that's bothering me is how can I predict the height of the div tag that holds the image? Please suggest the simplest way to perform this

```
<div style="background-image: url('img/bg.jpg'); background-size: 100%; width: 100%; height: 500px; ">

</div>
```

How the background should look like:
[image]

Comment: Utilize twitter-bootstraps [responsive image](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images)

Comment: Look at the provided example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, you can use vw and vh, as a percentage of the view. So if you say:

`div {
    height: 100vh;
}`

This div would take up the full vertical space of the view. vw is for width.